# How to prove nondifferentiability?

Tags: calculus

Prove that the the function $f(x) = |x-1|+|x-2|$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$ and $x = 2$.

This is actually an objective-type question where there are $3$ other options  $(\{0\},\{1\},\{3\},\{1,2\})$, now the problem is graph is not really much of a choice, hence I guess I have to break the functions into ranges and then solve; any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Show that the limits
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$
and
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$$
do not exist.

In each case, the easiest thing will be to consider the one sided limits, as $h\to 0^+$ and as $h\to 0^{-}$; if you can show that the one-sided limits are different from each other or at least one does not exist (including the case that they equal $\infty$ or $-\infty$), (each of the two limits separately, of course), then this will prove the function is not differentiable, because $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$ exists.

*After the edit*: There is a very big difference between "How can I choose the right answer from a given list of possibilities quickly?" and "How do I prove that the function is not differentiable at $x=1$ and $x=2$?" Please try to ask the question you mean to ask and not something different, lest you get an answer for the question you ask instead of for the question you *mean.*

The key here is that you should know by now that $y=|t|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $t=0$ (the standard example of a function that is continuous at a point but not differentiable there). That means that a horizontal translate of the function by $a$ (that is, the function $y=|t-a|$, which is the function $y=|t|$ "translated" $a$ units to the right) will necessarily be differentiable everywhere except at $t=a$.

So, $y=|x-1|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $x=1$, and $y=|x-2|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $x=2$. The sum of two functions is differentiable everywhere that the two functions are differentiable, and there is a chance that if *neither* function is differentiable at a point $a$, then their sum *will* be differentiable (for example, take $y=|x|$ and $y=-|x|$; neither is differentiable at $x=0$, but $|x|-|x|$ *is*). However, if **exactly one** of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable at $x=a$, then $f(x)+g(x)$ is **not** differentiable at $x=a$: say $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$, and so is $f+g$. Then $g= (f+g)-f$ is also differentiable at $x=a$, being the sum of two functions that are differentiable at $x=a$.

So, here, you have that $y=|x-1|+|x-2|$ is certainly differentiable at every $x$ that is not equal to either $1$ or $2$, because both $|x-1|$ and $|x-2|$ are differentiable there; and it is certainly **not** differentiable at either $x=1$ or $x=2$, because one and only one of $|x-1|$ and $|x-2|$ is differentiable at each of those points. So that tells you quickly that the right answer has to be $\{1,2\}$.

In general, you should know at a glance that $y=|x-a|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $x=a$.

Comment: "if you can show that the one-sided limits are different from each other" -- this is not sufficient in the case where both diverge. I have seen many a mathematician treat $\infty$ as limit "value", therefore the comment.

Comment: @Raphael: Well, *I* say that a limit that is "equal to $\infty$" does *not* exist; writing that the limit "is" $\infty$ is just a way of saying exactly *why* it does not exist. Ah, to have to take into account abusers of language...

Comment: Sorry for upsetting you. Was just trying to make the answer as clear as possible for people that are used to abuse of notation.

Comment: @Raphael: You didn't upset me. That was just a general sigh, as in, "why are there so many people in the world who aren't as sensible as *I* am?"

Comment: We all have these moments, don't we? Me, every time I see somebody use $\subset$ where $\subseteq$ is meant.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at the function $f(x)=|x|$. What happens to the graph when $x=0$? If we try finding the derivative, we have

$f^\prime(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{|x+\epsilon|-|x|}{\epsilon}$

This approaches 1, but if we try to compute $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} \frac{|x+\epsilon|-|x|}{\epsilon}$ we get -1. However, for the derivative to exist, the limit must be unique.